# Music in written form

Tags: fiction, description, music

I have a very hard time describing music in my writing. There's a particular scene where two characters are dancing along to piano music. It's a nice, romantic moment where they're the only people around on an empty street with piano music coming from a window.

My problem is that the only way I know how to describe it sounds very robotic.

"The melody was slow and sweet." "The notes played up and down in a romantic melody." You get the picture.

Anybody have any suggestions to make it sound better?

Comment: This is where literary devices really come in handy. You can use a simile. "The music floated and flew like a graceful bird." You can use a metaphor. "The music was a whirlwind tearing through every corner of the room." You can use personification. "The music fluttered and danced, happy to be free and grateful to be at the party."

Comment: https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2):

If it is a "nice, romantic moment," then make the emotions felt by the characters present parallel to the emotions evoked by the music. This shouldn't be very hard, as the atmosphere of the area, if it is romantic, will be partly due to the music.

Basically, I would just link the music to the characters' thoughts and feelings.